# Cannot import pynput

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-19.04

When executing the

```
import pynput
```

command in a script, I get this:

```
marc@boop:~$ python3
Python 3.7.5rc1 (default, Oct  8 2019, 16:47:45) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pynput
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py",         line 85, in _from_symbol
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line 131, in from_vk
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line     62, in __init__
ValueError: {'is_media': True}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 105, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 156, in Key
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 102, in _from_media
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_xorg.py", line 90, in _from_symbol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line 131, in from_vk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput-1.5.0-py3.7.egg/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line 62, in __init__
ValueError: {'is_media': True}
>>>
```

I have tried installing pynput through pip as well as from the github repo.

I am on python version 3.7 in Ubuntu 19.10.

If I can provide any additional info, please ask.
 Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip and reinstalling pynput?

Comment: @wishmaster yes, and pip can successfully install other libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was downgrading pynput from 1.5 to 1.4.5. It appears that 1.5 is unsupported on my system.